# Pointer Array Malloc (C Programming)

Tags: c

I found this one line that I don't understand. It says

```
char (*storage)[15] = malloc(sizeof *storage * 8)
```

Does anybody know what this is mean? why I see a lot of `*`?

I don't get it because why he/she multiplied by 8 (it seems like that) but then declared it was `[15]` too?

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=char+%28*storage%29%5B15%5D (http://bit.ly/1WpCOWp)

Comment: @ForceBru you read my mind.

Comment: In other words, `storage` is now an array of 8 elements, each of which is an array of 15 chars.

Comment: @ForceBru & Erik: It says syntax error bad character `"="` :(

Comment: @John, this site is for declaration deciphering only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char (*storage)[15] = malloc(sizeof *storage * 8)
```

It allocates memory for `8` character arrays of size `15` .

For all `*` you ask-

```
char (*storage)[15]              // pointer to array of 15 chars
```

and this -

```
sizeof *storage * 8   // this is 8 times sizeof type to which storage points
```

Comment: Ahh I see. Is there any alternative (much simpler) way to define it?

Comment: @John Yes , you can write like this -`char storage[8][15];`.

Comment: Now that seems familiar to me! Thank you.

Comment: @ameyCU And how do you `free()` that?

Comment: @Rm32a Which one are you talking about ?

Comment: @ameyCU How do you free `char (*storage)[15] = malloc(sizeof *storage * 8)`?

Comment: @Rm32a `free(storage);` should do ,as we allocate memory to it .

Comment: `char *storage = malloc(15*8)` is **not** the same as `char (*storage)[15] = malloc(sizeof *storage * 8)`. Although the same amount of memory is allocated, `storage` behaves completely different in case pointer arithmetics are applied to it.

Comment: @alk Yes Sir,  clearly they point to different type of objects .

Comment: @Rm32a: Please see my last comment above.

Answer (score 1):

`char (*storage)[15]` is a pointer to 15-element array of `char`.

`sizeof *storage * 8` is 8 times the size of the type at which `storage` points.

Comment: Ah I see. Is there any alternative (much simpler) way to define it?

Answer (score 0):

```
char (*storage)[15] = malloc(sizeof *storage * 8);
```

*dynamically* allocates an 8x15 array of `char`.  This is roughly similar to writing

```
char storage[8][15];
```

except that

- The *lifetime* of a dynamically-allocated object lasts until it is explicitly deallocated with `free`, whereas the lifetime of an automatically-allocated object lasts until the program exits the object's enclosing scope;

  The storage for a dynamically-allocated object is (usually) taken from a different memory segment than automatically-allocated objects;

  You can extend the size of a dynamically-allocated array as necessary.  IOW, if you realized you needed two more rows, you could write

  ```
  size_t curRows = 8;
  char (*tmp)[15] = realloc( storage, sizeof *storage * (curRows + 2));
  if ( tmp )
  {
    storage = tmp;
    curRows += 2;
  }
  ```

  You can't do that with an automatically-allocated array.

An alternate way of dynamically allocating an 8x15 array is something like this:

```
char **storage = malloc( sizeof *storage * 8 );
if ( storage )
{
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < 8; i++ )
  {
    storage[i] = malloc( sizeof *storage[i] * 15 );
  }
}
```

Note that all three versions can be indexed as `storage[i][j]`.

The main advantage of the last method is that each row can be different lengths if you want them to be.  The main disadvantages are that the rows won't necessarily be adjacent in memory, and you have to `free` each `storage[i]` before you can `free` `storage`.